# Get column value of database object in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, jquery

I wrote a line in my script that saves the id of an object from my database thats selected in a select field. Looks like this:

```
var dep_id = $("#select_field" option:selected").val()
```

Depending on the dep_id the script is supposed to alter the selected value of another select field like this:

```
if (dep_id == 2) {
        document.getElementById("scope").selectedIndex = 2;
}
else {
        document.getElementById("scope").selectedIndex = 1;
}
```

Beside an id the selected object always has a name. What I now want to do is replace the dep_id with the actual name of that object in this script but I dont know how I get the name.

So what do I have to do to catch the object name by using the id?

Comment: Your selector is not right. It has to be: `$("#select_field option:selected").val()`

Comment: var name = document.getElementById("scope").innerText || document.getElementById("scope").textContent;